# PDF Data lost when uploading to Firebase storage using Pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase, pdf, flask, firebase-storage

Hi I have the following code snippet.

```
import pyrebase
config = {
"apiKey": "Xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"authDomain": "xxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
"databaseURL": "xxxxxxxfirebaseio.com",
"projectId": "xxxxxxxxx",
"storageBucket": "xxxxxxx",
"messagingSenderId": "111111"
}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase.storage()
storage.child("images/example.pdf").put(filename)
storage.child("images/example.pdf").download("downloaded.pdf")
```

Now, I have tried passing both the file path available as **/Users/myname/project/filename.pdf** as well as the File object available at the runtime, since the file is coming from a Form submission as **FileStorage: filename.pdf' ('application/pdf')** to the put method.

Status 200 is returned from Firebase and the path as "images/example.pdf" is created on the console.

However, the content of the file is lost. When I try downloading the file on the Firebase console it says, **Error Failed to load PDF document.**

When I try using code i.e. the last line in the attached snippet containing the download method, the file is downloaded from Firebase but it's empty.

Tried cloning pyrebase as well, everything seems alright there.

Looking for some help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The put statement accepts a byte stream file object. Hence, put((open = "/path/to/PDF/file", "rb") works.